# Reuse expectations block several times in JMockit

Tags: java, junit, liferay, jmockit

I am writing test cases for a liferay portal in which I want to mock ActionRequest, ThemeDisplay kind of objects. I have tried with writing expectations in each test method.

Now I want to generalize the approach by creating a BaseTest class which provides me all expectations needed for each method so that I don't have to write it again in the all test classes.

For one class I have tried by writing expectations in @Before method. How can I use same in different classes?

For example I want to do following in several classes:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    // All expectations which are required by each test methods
    new Expectations() {{
        themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker();
        returns(permissionChecker);
        actionRequest.getParameter("userId");
        returns("111");
        actionRequest.getParameter("userName");
        returns("User1");
    }};

}
```

Also is there a way to provide that whenever I call `actionRequest.getParameter()` it may return the specific value which I provide?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, what you want is to create *named* `Expectations` and `Verifications` subclasses to be reused from multiple test classes. Examples can be found in the [documentation](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#reuse).

Note that mocked instances have to be passed in, when instantiating said subclasses.

Methods like `getPermissionChecker()`, however, usually don't need to be explicitly recorded, since a cascaded instance is going to be automatically returned as needed.

Mocking methods like `getParameter`, though, hints that perhaps it would be better to use *real* objects rather than mocks. Mocking isn't really meant for simple "getters", and this often indicates that you may be mocking too much.